# JQuery function working on hard coded table but not dynamic generated content

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a Web app that is a in browser invoice generator tool.  I  have a jQuery script that  calculates the total for that item,  dynamic changes the per unit cost depending on the task you are invoicing for and add new items (table rows) to the invoice,  my code works fine on any items hard coded into the table,  but any items jQuery appends to the table the script won't calculate the values.

Items are appended  with 
`$('#id').append() ;`

Script here: http://jsfiddle.net/hb6mmkss/

note: the script is not working in my jsfiddle for some reason but works fine in the browser but u can still see the code.

Can anyone see why this may be happening?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input').keyup(function(){ 
  $parent = $(this).parent().attr('class');
  if( $("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "page"){
   $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('75');
  }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "content"){
   $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('50');
  }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "wp"){
   $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('300');
  }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "store"){
   $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('150');
  }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "store-items"){
   $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('12.50');
  }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "seo"){
   $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('50');
  }

  function calcInd($parent){
   $unit = $('.' + $parent + '>.unit').val();
   $quant = $('.' + $parent + '>.quant').val();
   $total =  $unit * $quant;
   $('.' + $parent + '>.it-total').val($total);
  };
  calcInd($parent);
  });

  $('#add').click(function(){
   $newClass = $('#main-table tr').length;
   $newRow = '<tr><td class="it-' + $newClass + '"><select><option value="page">Web Pages</option><option value="content">Content for pages</option><option value="wp">Wordpress Install / Config</option><option value="store">eCommerce Setup</option><option value="store-items">eCommerce Store Items Data Entry</option><option value="seo">On Page SEO</option></select></td><td class="it-' + $newClass + '"><input type="text" class="quant"></td><td class="it-' + $newClass + '"><input type="text" class="unit"></td><td class="it-' + $newClass + '"><input type="text" class="it-total"></td></tr>';
   $('#main-table').append($newRow);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table id="main-table">
 <thead>
  <th>
   <td>
    <h3>Item / Task</h3>
   </td>
   <td>
    <h3>Quantity/Hours</h3>
   </td>
   <td>
    <h3>Unit Price</h3>
   </td>
   <td>
    <h3>Item /Task Total</h3>
   </td>
  </th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="it-1">
    <select>
     <option value="page">Web Pages</option>
     <option value="content">Content for pages</option>
     <option value="wp">Wordpress Install / Config</option>
     <option value="store">eCommerce Setup</option>
     <option value="store-items">eCommerce Store Items Data Entry</option>
     <option value="seo">On Page SEO</option>
    </select>
   </td>
   <td class="it-1">
    <input type="text" class="quant">
   </td>
   <td class="it-1">
    <input type="text" class="unit">
   </td>
   <td class="it-1">
    <input type="text" class="it-total">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Add Row+</buttom>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (**As of jQuery 1.7**)  [`jQuery.fn.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)to achieve that functionality.

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

Try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<script src="res/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main-table').on("keyup","input",function(){
        alert("keyup!");    
        $parent = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        if( $("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "page"){
            $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('75');
        }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "content"){
            $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('50');
        }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "wp"){
            $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('300');
        }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "store"){
            $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('150');
        }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "store-items"){
            $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('12.50');
        }else if($("." + $parent + ">select").val() == "seo"){
            $("." + $parent + ">.unit").val('50');
        }

        function calcInd($parent){
            $unit = $('.' + $parent + '>.unit').val();
            $quant = $('.' + $parent + '>.quant').val();
            $total =  $unit * $quant;
            $('.' + $parent + '>.it-total').val($total);
        };
        calcInd($parent);
    });

    $('#add').on("click",function(){
      alert("clicked!");
        $newClass = $('#main-table tr').length;
        $newRow = '<tr><td class="it-' + $newClass + '"><select><option value="page">Web Pages</option><option value="content">Content for pages</option><option value="wp">Wordpress Install / Config</option><option value="store">eCommerce Setup</option><option value="store-items">eCommerce Store Items Data Entry</option><option value="seo">On Page SEO</option></select></td><td class="it-' + $newClass + '"><input type="text" class="quant"></td><td class="it-' + $newClass + '"><input type="text" class="unit"></td><td class="it-' + $newClass + '"><input type="text" class="it-total"></td></tr>';
        $('#main-table').append($newRow);
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<body>
<table id="main-table">
    <thead>
        <th>
            <td>
                <h3>Item / Task</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>Quantity/Hours</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>Unit Price</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>Item /Task Total</h3>
            </td>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="it-1">
                <select>
                    <option value="page">Web Pages</option>
                    <option value="content">Content for pages</option>
                    <option value="wp">Wordpress Install / Config</option>
                    <option value="store">eCommerce Setup</option>
                    <option value="store-items">eCommerce Store Items Data Entry</option>
                    <option value="seo">On Page SEO</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="it-1">
                <input type="text" class="quant">
            </td>
            <td class="it-1">
                <input type="text" class="unit">
            </td>
            <td class="it-1">
                <input type="text" class="it-total">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Add Row+</buttom>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fair enough,  but how will that fix the issue? All my code works,  but when I append a new item,  all the. keyup() stuff doesn't run on the new element that have been created. Could it be because they were generated after the Page load?

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions See Answer. Sorry for the delay!